# Zend Framework 2 segment route required segment

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-framework-routing

I am trying to make a route (or two) that will let me invoke two different actions with the below URL formats.

```
mydomain.com/profile
mydomain.com/profile/1234/something
```

For the second format, the `1234` should be a required integer value, while `something` should be an optional string. The first format is simple by using a literal route. I thought I could add a segment child route for the second format, but I cannot get it to work. I tried to leave out the first format and only do the second one with a segment route, but I wasn't successful in that either.

Here is what I tried:

```
'profile' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/profile',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action' => 'profile'
        )
    ),
    'child_routes' => array(
        'profile_view' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:code[/:username]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'code' => '[0-9]*',
                    'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action' => 'view_profile'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

For `mydomain.com/profile`, I get the following errror:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided'
```

For `mydomain.com/1234/something`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Missing parameter "code"'
```

The [manual states the following](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment):

> If a segment is optional, it should be surrounded by brackets. As an
>   example, “/:foo[/:bar]” would match a “/” followed by text and assign
>   it to the key “foo”; if any additional “/” characters are found, any
>   text following the last one will be assigned to the key “bar”.

Is that not exactly what I am doing? The above errors remain the same if I comment out the constraints.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with it some more. After debugging, I still couldn't figure it out. I tried to add a default value to the `code` parameter and that seemed to do the trick. Why on Earth that works and how it makes sense, I have no idea. To me it shouldn't matter if I have a default value specified or not if I have provided a value in the URL for the parameter in the URL. Nevertheless, apparently it does matter - or at least in this case it did.

Here is the working code. I also updated the regular expression for the code parameter.

```
'profile' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/profile',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action'     => 'profile',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'view' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:code[/:username]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'code' => '\d+',
                    'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action' => 'viewProfile',
                    'code' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Adding a default parameter works, because now you supply a value for code via the defaults. Though you *should* have provided one when calling the assemble method.

Comment: Interestingly, I can get the `code` parameter just fine in my controller, and it is not 0 (i.e. the default value). Rather, it is the value that I write in the URL, which is what I wanted anyways.

Comment: This should not be marked as the answer; it is only a band aid.  I posted what I think is the answer below.  Please look at it.

Answer (score 5):

**My solution: Set the default for your optional parameter to empty string**

I ran into a similar problem, I solved it by setting the default value for the optional parameter (in your case "username" to an empty string ""; My solution:

```
'users' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/users[/:user_id]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'user_id' => '[0-9]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'My\Controller\User',
            'user_id' => ""
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The second exception you get `Missing parameter "code"` comes from assembling, not matching. This means that you didn't supply the code when assembling the route `profile/profile_view`.

By the way, you don't have to prefix your child_routes with the parent routes' name. Just call the child route "view", and assemble it as `profile/view`.

Comment: You are right that the error is with assembling and not matching. However, that still doesn't make sense to me. Nevertheless, I seem to have figured out what the problem was (even though I don't understand it). By adding a default value to the code parameter, things seems to work. Strange! Also, thanks for the heads up about the naming. Actually it was just a coincidence that I named it like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the `may_terminate` option, like so:

```
'profile' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/profile',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
            'action' => 'profile'
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. `mydomain.com/profile` works, but `mydomain.com/profile/`, `mydomain.com/profile/1234` and `mydomain.com/1234/something` all give me the error stating that the `code` parameter is missing.

Comment: There is no route that would satisfy `mydomain.com/profile/` as the trailing slash puts you in the child route and then `:code` becomes required. Does this route work if the constraints are removed from `:code`? Otherwise I would be looking to disable `:username` and simply get the route working with `/profile/1234` and `/profile`.

Comment: Yes, I was not expecting `mydomain.com/profile/` to work, but I was wondering why it even matched with the child route when a required parameter was not supplied. Anyways, removing the constraints does not make a difference. Completely removing the username from the route also doesn't make a difference. I still get the same error message. I have checked all of my other routes, and none of them should interfere with my new route. I have tried to disable some, but with the same results. It is matching the correct route anyways, so that is not the problem. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: It maybe worth diving into the segment route code and check the values and instance state before that exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons this occurs according to Bittarman. The main reason, he says, is:

```
<Bittarman> ezio, that looks like what happens when you make a new phprenderer rather than using the configured one
```

I had the lesser of the reason apparently:
I was using $this->url() in my layout.  Because there was no route match--a 404 error--it was blowing up on all 404 errors.

```
<Bittarman> for all of those things, stop doing if (!$this->url() == $this->url('home') etc
<ezio> ummm when it's home my business partner wants the whole order changed so google can hit on a bunch of keyords
<Bittarman> instead, in the VIEW for home, set what you need.
<ezio> how would i set the second example where i'm trying to highlight the currently-being-used menu item
<Bittarman> so, in your layout, you just want echo $this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ')->setAutoEscape(false)
<Bittarman> ezio, use the placeholder view helper
<ezio> okay
<ezio> thanks Bittarman ... tearing my hair out is not fun when you're already losing so much of it :p
<Bittarman> <?= $this->placeholder('currently-being-used') ?>
<Bittarman> and in your view, <?php $this->placeholder('currently-being-used')->append('foo') ?>
<ezio> sense making a lot you are
```

Comment: how does this answer the OP?